# ¿Obtener eventos en control creado? Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, vb

tengo un problema con el cual he batallado horas y espero alguien pueda ayudarme:
Estoy trabajando en un sistema el cual los clientes manejarán, quite los bordes del formulario para evitar que lo cierren los clientes bromeando o tal, entonces añadí un botón "Salir" donde al darle clic se crearan 2 controles: 1 label que da indicaciones y un EditText donde se ingresa la contraseña para salir, el caso es que al crear estos controles, no están definidos sus eventos en el código, y quiero saber como hacer eso, me refiero a los eventos como los del botón "Button1_Click" y tal, les adjunto el código del botón que crea estos controles:

```
Dim txtsalir As New TextBox  
Dim lblsalir As New Label  
Dim resDest As Size = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize  
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSalir.Click 'A esta linea me refiero  
 If btnSalir.Text = "Cancelar" Then  
  Me.Controls.Remove(txtsalir)  
  Me.Controls.Remove(lblsalir)  
  btnSalir.Text = "Salir"  
ElseIf btnSalir.Text = "Salir" Then 
  txtsalir.Font = New Font("Arial", 42, FontStyle.Regular,,GraphicsUnit.Pixel)  
  txtsalir.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center  
  txtsalir.PasswordChar = "*"  
  txtsalir.Width = resDest.Width / 2  
  Dim centrarw As Integer = resDest.Width / 2 - (txtsalir.Width / 2)  
  Dim centrarh As Integer = resDest.Height / 2  
  txtsalir.Location = New Point(centrarw, centrarh)  
  lblsalir.Text = "Ingresar contraseña para cerrar el sistema"  
  lblsalir.AutoSize = True  
  lblsalir.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center  
  lblsalir.Font = New Font("Arial", 42, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)  
  lblsalir.Location = New Point(centrarw, centrarh - 50)  
  Me.Controls.Add(txtsalir)  
  Me.Controls.Add(lblsalir)  
  txtsalir.Focus()  
  btnSalir.Text = "Cancelar"  
End If  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes ejecutar la instrucción [AddHandler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) para añadir al evento que necesitas de esos controles una función a ejecutar, de la siguiente manera:

```
AddHandler Control.Evento, AddressOf FuncionAEjecutar
```

Ejemplo con el `btnSalir`:

```
AddHandler btnSalir.Click, AddressOf Button1_Click
```

Puedes hacer esto para todos los controles que quieras siempre indicando la funcion que deben ejecutar.

Comment: He intentado insertando eso, pero el código no reconoce mi "txtsalir" ya que lo he declarado con código, ¿tienes alguna otra forma?

Comment: Al final lo he conseguido añadiendo las lineas que me dijiste y añadiendo la Sub Privada del evento.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertodeTriana Me alegro que te haya servido, no olvides marcar la respuesta que te ha ayudado como respuesta correcta a tu pregunta para que futuros usuarios puedan llegar a la solución mas intuitivamente.